# Unwanted silence in LMMS

Tags: software

There's a pause at the end of a segment of music, in the piano roll, in [LMMS](https://lmms.io/). How do I get rid of that pause? Do I use a loop point? If so, how do I set a loop point?

Thank you.

*Editor's note: LMMS is free, cross-platform music production software.*

Comment: If I rememember well, loop are quantized to bar length

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the audio during design, and not the final export? I'm not experiencing the same problem on my edition, but that could be a clue in itself. It sounds like an audio processing artifact.

I suggest two things—look into your buffer size under the Edit→Settings menu, and ensure that it's large enough (mine's at 1024 frames with a 23.2 ms latency, for reference). If that fails, try checking your Audio options under Settings (the one with the speaker icon on it) and ensure that you're using an effective audio interface, as some of them are more cooperative than others. SDL usually works for me.

Hopefully that will help solve your problem.